# How to show XML weather in sharepoint?

Tags: xslt, xml, elements-xml

I'm quite a newbie with sharepoint and especially in XML. I would like to show this weather info in my Sharepoint. I'm using XML web part & XSLT formatting.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Lappeenranta&mode=xml

I've read and tried few tutorials with XML & XSLT formatting, but I don't know how to handle with element attributes 
like

```
    <temperature value="273.57" min="273.15" max="274.82" unit="kelvin"/>
```

I'd like to display on "value" attribute.
Don't mind about the units =)

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

BR, Simo

Answer (score 1):

Without using the XML webpart and XSL you could use the Content Editor webpart, where you specify a file from a library in your site as source.

In this file you can write something like this:

```
<div id="weather-icon"></div>
<div id="weather-info"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.baseic = window.baseic || {};
window.baseic.FetchCurrentWeather = function()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=Lappeenranta&mode=json&units=metric&lang=fi",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        var city = data.name;
        var currentWeatherIcon = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
        var currentTemp = Math.round(data.main.temp);

        jQuery('#weather-icon').html("<img width='50' src='" + currentWeatherIcon + "' />");
        jQuery('#weather-info').html(city + ", " + currentTemp + " °C");
    }); 
}

jQuery(window.baseic.FetchCurrentWeather);

</script>
```

Note that this example code is highly dependent on jQuery so you would need to load it if it is not already available in your site.

Also note that I use json as mode instead of XML since it is easier to parse that in Javascript :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Being such a rookie I'm still stuck with this. I found "Content Editor" webpart, but I don't see any field to input code.

How about the jQuery, when I'm using Office 365 P1 Sharepoint?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx under "Adding content" you can see how to point to a file. Regarding jQuery in Office 365, you should be fine using the outcommented line above (ajax.google and so on)

Comment: Thanks! Now I got it, but webpart shows only it's title without any content? Does it matter what kind of file that script is? (txt, html..?)

And how to use that googleapi script?

Feeling kind a noob at the moment :D

Comment: you should use .txt You can just copy everything in my code above and place in i the .txt I guess

Comment: No success so far. I've placed that txt file in Intranet folder and pointed it for Content Editor webpart. I still cannot see any data, only default webpart subject. 

I found some more info and maybe I should modify the "masterpage" with Sharepoint Designer?

http://sp365.co.uk/2011/07/adding-jquery-to-sharepoint/
"You will need to open your MasterPage and add the following code to the header section preferably.

[code lang="js"]<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>[/code]"

Comment: It seems to be also Firefox related problem. I've run this test script: http://goo.gl/yKauKV
- With IE it works and popup opens, with Firefox nothing happens.

Could this be also FF related?
When I open your script in IE it says error
"Message: 'weather.0' is null or not an object". With FF I don't get any errors (or results).

Comment: Is your site loaded over HTTPS? if so you can remove the http: part of the script src.